# Gradle Docker tasks

Tags: postgresql, docker, gradle

For my local development tasks 
1. i want to ensure that the DB is running in the docker container which in this case is Postgres, i have a bootRun task defined in my build.gradle file

```
bootRun{
    jvmArgs = [
        "-Ddb.host=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
        "-Ddb.username=postgres",
        "-Ddb.password=apgdb"
    ]
}
```

and docker installed on my machine i just want to ensure that i do not have to manually go and start the postgres image from terminal and then do a bootRun, 
can we create a gradle task which can ensure that it restarts the postgres on every exit of bootRun and start everytime we spin the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [gradle-docker-compose plugin](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin) to achieve this kind of task. You can create a `docker-compose.yml` file that defines your postgres db:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: apgdb
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
```

And that would be the respective `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.avast.gradle.docker-compose" version "0.8.14"
}

dockerCompose {
    database {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose.yml']
    }
}

bootRun{
    dependsOn 'databaseComposeUp'
    jvmArgs = [
        "-Ddb.host=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
        "-Ddb.username=postgres",
        "-Ddb.password=apgdb"
    ]
}
```

Now when you run `gradle bootRun` it will start up the database before spring boots up.